# Printing values using Iterator for LinkedList, keep getting infinite loop in java

Tags: java, list, iterator

So i am coding a doubly linked list implementation in java and i need to print out values so that I can test to see if the code works. However, for the past couple of days ive been trying to figure out why I keep getting an infinite loop. Here's my code:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> implements LinkedListInterface<T>, Iterable<T>{

private Node<T> head;
private Node<T> tail;
private int size;

//add, remove, clear, isempty methods, etc.

private class LinkedListIterator<E> implements java.util.Iterator<E> {

    private Node<E> probe;

    public LinkedListIterator(Node<T> head) {
        probe = (Node<E>)(head);
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (probe!= null);
    }

    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("There is no element.");
        }
        E temp = probe.getData();
        probe = probe.getNext();
        return temp;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("We don't support this function.");
    }

}
```

I tried printing out the values but I just get a single value repeated infinitely. What's going on? Much help would be appreciated. In main, this is what I have:

```
    DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(0, 1);
    list.add(1, 2);
    for (Integer i : list) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
```

Here is the code for the Node Class:

```
public class Node<E> {

private E data;
private Node<E> next;
private Node<E> prev;

public Node(E data) {
    //do I need this?
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    //TODO
    return data + " ";
}
// Implement Methods
public E getData() {
    return data;
}
public Node<E> getNext() {
    return next;
}
public Node<E> getPrev() {
    return prev;
}

public void setData(E e) {
    data = e;
}
public void setNext(Node<E> e) {
    next = e;
}
public void setPrev(Node<E> e) {
    prev = e;
}

}
```

EDIT: Here is my add method:

```
    public boolean add(int index, T data) {
    // TODO
    boolean toReturn = false;
    if (data == null) return false;
    if (index == 0) {
        Node<T> toAdd = new Node<T>(data);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = toAdd;
            tail = toAdd;
        } else {
            head.setPrev(toAdd);
        }
        toAdd.setNext(head);
        head = toAdd;
        toReturn = true;
    } else if (index == size()) {
        Node<T> toAdd = new Node<T>(data);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = toAdd;
            tail = toAdd;
        } else {
            tail.setNext(toAdd);
            toAdd.setPrev(tail);
        }
        tail = toAdd;
        toReturn = true;
    } else {
        Node<T> toAdd = new Node<T>(data);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = toAdd;
            tail = toAdd;
        } else {
            getNodeAt(index).setPrev(toAdd);
        }
        toAdd.setNext(getNodeAt(index));
        getNodeAt(index-1).setNext(toAdd);
        toReturn = true;
    }
    size++;
    return toReturn;
}
```

The following is my getNodeAt() method:

```
    private Node<T> getNodeAt(int index) {
    int count = 0;
    Node<T> element = head;
    while (element !=  null) {
        if (count == index) {
            return element;
        } else {
            count++;
            element = element.getNext();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the DoublyLinkedList please.

Comment: What's with the weird casting in the constructor?

Comment: Do you have implemented `equals` and `hashcode` in your `DoublyLinkedList`?

Comment: I just updated my code

Comment: Please post your DoublyLinkedList class

Comment: Can you post your `getNodeAt` method?

Comment: Ok, it has been posted

Answer (score 1):

I am willing to bet your problem is in the Node (which you dont supply the code).  Check that Node.getNext() is actually returning the next node and not a reference to itself.

Comment: does your add method appropriately call the setNext()/setPrevious() method?

Comment: I think so. i have supplied my add() method above. It removes based off of if it needs to be added to the front, middle or end.

Comment: Tony the Pony is correct that you don;t call setPrevious on toAdd.  Also check the isEmpty() method.  Also, if index=size(), you need to setNext() on the node tail.getPrevious();

Comment: do you still have the infinite loop when you list.add(0,1); list.add(0,2) ?  This way you never use the second part of the if-then.  Also, make sure that index is not larger than size().

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your `add` method. When an element is inserted in the middle of the list, your code fails to set the link to the previous sibling of `toAdd`.

As a result, somewhere in the flow of your program, adding and removing elements might result in the list becoming corrupt.

That's my best guess without looking at the rest of your code.

Comment: But wouldn't that be irrelevant in this case considering that I am adding to empty list which would trigger an insertion to the front (1st if case), and then another addition which would insert to the back (2nd if case). The else (middle insertion) shouldn't be running. On a side note, I also realized that my second condition should be: else if (index == size()-1) and I have changed that and it still hasn't worked.